# Generalization of Brouwer's fixed point theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

Following is the question from Lawvere and Schanuel's book "Conceptual Mathematics".
[image]

Here is what I think, how to explain the situation:

1) In category of continuous maps $\exists s: D \rightarrow D$ such that $g \circ s = 1_D$.

2) $s \circ f$ is a continuous map on $D$. (I think, composition of two functions is also a continuous function)

3) Using Brouwer's fixed point theorem on $D$, $\exists d:1 \rightarrow D$ such that, $(s \circ f) \circ d = d$.

4) Now, this means that

$$g \circ (s \circ f) \circ d = g \circ d$$

Using Associative identity,

$$(g \circ s) \circ f \circ d = g \circ d$$

Using $g \circ s = 1_D$,

$$1_D \circ f \circ d = g \circ d$$

Using associative identity,

$$f \circ d = g \circ d$$

Q.E.D.

Note that, I have not used the given inclusion map. Thus, it applies to all maps on D, which have a section.

But, I do not know yet, how to explain the existence of a section for g, which is a consequence of inclusion map and continuity of g, as section is not implied by any one of properties.

Thanks

**Update-0**: It could be done with a generalized version of Intermediate Value theorem, I think. Where, boundary of a geometric objects acts like an interval.